# how to close current window in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I want to take a value in session then close the current window.

```
if(isset($_POST['ok']))
{
echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "closeCurrentWindow()";
echo "</script>";;
}
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Why don't you redirected (using header('location:your path to redirect')) to your desired page other than closing the window?

Comment: NO, you DON'T want to close the users window.

Comment: Where is closeCurrentWindow() defintion how the hell we can know it? I agree with @NullVoid instead of closing window redirect user. To close window you can use `if isset($_POST['ok']) echo '<script>window.close()</script>';` if you think that is the best solution use this code

Comment: here i want open a new tab to select items on selecting items i have to close that window and i want that item also?

Comment: thanks  Robert Podwika,i hope this will solve my problem

Answer (score 10):

```
if(isset($_POST['ok']))
{
echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "window.close();";
echo "</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you define closeCurrentWindow() somewhere? You can't just make up functions and expect them to work :)

Try `window.close()`. Be aware of its limitations though:

> The close method closes only windows opened by JavaScript using the open method. If you attempt to close any other window, a confirm message is displayed, asking the user to choose whether the window is to be closed or not.

Source: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

    function openWin()
    {
    myWindow=window.open("","","width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
    }

    function closeWin()
    {
    myWindow.close();
    }

</script>
```